# Set rootInterfaceController in Apple Watch's "ExtensionDelegate"

Tags: ios, storyboard, apple-watch, wkinterfacecontroller

I am making a Apple Watch app and I'd like to set different root view controllers, depending on an initial condition.

I cannot set the WatchKit rootInterfaceController directly though, because it is a readonly property, but by checking [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtension_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKExtension/rootInterfaceController), they say it is possible to set it "before the launch sequence finishes".

Do you have a good suggestion to do that? Maybe through the storyboard?

Comment: You can't set read only property!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't set read only property, you can do something like,

Create some SplashController, with some splash screen, and in `awakeWithContext`

```
 override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
      super.awakeWithContext(context)
 }
```

track something that you need, after track present some controllers, for example

```
   if !isCounting {
    self.presentControllerWithName("Interface", context: nil)
} else {
    self.presentControllerWithName("Timer", context: nil)
}
```

`isCounting` is stored in NSUserDefaults

hope this will help :)